# Frequently Asked Questions on Blender Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, questions

Anyone who's been around this site for a while, has seen the never ending cycle of the same questions being asked over and over again.

Users hardly ever use the search function... and the search engine... is not good at all...

Just like there is a [resources page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender), should there be a FAQ one linking to the highest quality posts?

I propose having 20 to 25 FAQ to start and find out their usefulness.

The list could work as a form of troubleshooting list either for users to find their own answers or for folks writing answers looking for a known duplicate.

Propposed format:

- Commonly asked problem/question as header.
- Possible causes of the issue.
- Each one of the causes can be then linked to a post that has an accepted or high quality answer that explains the issue and solution in detail.

Comment: That proposal was from back when SE sites *had* FAQ pages. It's now called the Help Center. Perhaps we could make a page in the Help Center to collect all the frequent questions, canonical answers and other resources.

Comment: The difference is that this shouldn't be about the rules for the site but questions about blender that get asked every other day. Things like "My render is blank", "armature deforms strangely" "enable GPU" "background images" "audio and video don't match" "boolean not working" etc.

Comment: Here is a good start for an FAQ. "Ugly black artifacts on my model!" - *Z fighting.* "I can see through my model!" - *Normals*. "Cross hair thing keeps moving and I can't select anything" - *Right click noob*. "I keep pressing 'p' and I can't start my game" *your in blender internal or cycles. change to the BGE.* "My render is all black" - *add a lamp*. "Buy overpriced sneakers" - *flag as spam*. "I have no idea what to ask, but I have a problem" - *you certainly do.* "How do I make my model look as cool as gandalf's test scenes?" - *add a Suzanne and be Gandalf.*

Comment: The SE way is to immediately mark these as duplicates and encourage people to search but as usual since we have a stricter scope (software), I could see this being useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Helpful post reference index](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/867/helpful-post-reference-index)

Comment: @Gwenn i feel like merging this with the other list would just result in clutter. The other list seems more resource/theory oriented while this is about very specific issues and found solutions.

Comment: Somewhat related: I created a [similar list](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/867/helpful-post-reference-index) a little while ago for *answers* I find myself linking to a lot.  (i.e. in-site "see he for more information on <x>" links.)  It didn't get much attention though.

Comment: @Gwenn - I added that link (http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/867/helpful-post-reference-index) to the "FAQ" answer below

Answer (score 19):

Proposed FAQ questions

**Feel free to edit:**

## Where can I find links to learn blender

- [Resources for blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

## Black artifacts / Strange shadows / Some faces are black or darker than others

- [Z fighting caused by overlapping geometry, remove doubles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698) (Alternative answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/5426))
- [Normals are flipped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3606/2217)
- [Not enough transparent bounces when using transparent materials in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026)
- [Z-fighting caused by depth precision on very large distances between clipping points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23672/rendering-artifacts-in-blender-internal/23693#23693)

## Pink textures

- [Missing Textures, Images not packed or file path broken](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/5426)
- Texture coordinates set incorrectly
- [Trying to use blender materials on cycles render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27105/texture-appears-pink-in-blender-render/27108#27108)

## GPU Rendering

- [Enable GPU](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)
- [OpenCL in AMD, (non Nvidia) Cards](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48813/gpu-rendering-on-amd-radeon-hd-6800-series/48819#48819)
- [Older Nvidia GPUs (lower than cuda 2.0)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-enable-gpu-rendering-on-older-nvidia-gpus/1475#1475)

## Render is blank

- There are no lights in scene
- [Objects disabled for Render in Outliner (camera icon)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/one-object-wont-show-up-in-final-render-even-though-it-shows-up-in-the-preview/27722#27722)
- [Strips in VSE and Sequencer box enabled in Post-Processing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51179/blank-image-when-i-render/51181#51181)
- [Objects in different layer or not part of the render Layers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35020/1853)
- Camera view blocked by other objects
- Active camera set incorrectly or aiming in a different direction
- [An object in the scene has been set as camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this)
- [Output node in compositor disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UtY8.png)
- [Film exposure is set to 0 (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51951/my-render-is-turning-out-black/51957#51957)
- [The scene is so out of focus that there is no recognizable image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55410/1853)
- [Scene was created using cycles and will render all gray in blender render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77042/blender-renders-gray-full-screen/77045#77045)
- A COMPILATION OF MANY OF THESE ANSERS found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

## My cycles render is fuzzy/noisy

- [use denoise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86225/1853)
- [Render Samples set too low](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)
- [Samples set on render layer override regular sample settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42947/1853).
- [Lights or environment not set to multiple importance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/when-should-mis-be-used-and-when-should-it-be-disabled/5397#5397). Aditionally [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/what-is-multiple-importance-sample-option/8156#8156)
- [render resolution is set to less than 100%](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated)
- Use [branched path tracing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful) instead of the default samples

## Differences between Renderers: Cycles, Blender Internal, and Game Engine

- [Cycles vs internal vs game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/60486/2217)
- [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5820/2217)
- [Cycles vs Internal for a small animated outdoor scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7300/2217)

## Armature deforms strangely

## Boolean not working

- A comprehensive answer of boolean issues on [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/1853)
- [Non-Manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/1853)
- [Inconsistent normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50632/1853)
- [Booleans don't work with curves or text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27151/1853)
- [The scale for the object uses negative values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56587/boolean-doesnt-work)

## Missing background images

- [3D view not in camera perspective any of the preset orthogonal views](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing)
- [Background images not visible in render mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode)
- [Background images not present in final render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464)

## VSE audio and video don't match

- [Framerate of imported video and blender project mismatch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/video-editing-audio-and-video-strip-have-different-length)
- Codec issues with GOP size
- [Audio using different frequency than that of project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/blenders-video-and-audio-dont-sync-when-editing)
- video compressed using variable framerate
- Video needs to be cached before playback
- AV Sync has to be enabled for playback

## See through an object/Object missing parts

- [Clip distance set incorrectly for 3D viewport or camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554)
- [Normals are Flipped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30938/5426)

## Object not rendering but visible in preview

- [Rendering is disabled for object in outliner (camera icon)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50891/1853)
- Object in layer not included in render layer
- [Ray visibility to camera disabled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered/33790#33790)

## Imported object has no texture

- Textures were not packed
- [Imported OBJ object has no .mtl associated](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024)
- there are no materials assigned to the mesh,
- [the .obj importer does not create materials in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-can-i-get-a-mtl-file-to-show-on-an-obj-model-i-imported-in-cycles).

## Exported object is missing textures

- [Exported format is not compatible with blender materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)
- [Bake Textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

## Moving selected vertices/edges/faces, moves unselected ones as well

- [Proportional Editing is enabled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57323/everything-moves-not-just-the-selected-vertex) Disable pressing <kbd>O</kbd> [Alternative answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27395/1853).

## Switched to/from Cycles to Internal materials are gone.

- [how is cycles different than internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)
- [convert materials from internal to cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)
- [Mix different scenes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/can-i-use-cycles-materials-with-blender-internal)

## Mirror Modifier creates a gap or a crease in the middle of the model.

- [Mirror modifier should be used before the subsurf modifier in the stack.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52164/why-cant-i-merge-two-vertices/52167#52167)
- [There are interior faces on the model at the edge of the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh)

## How to combine Smooth and Sharp Edges?

- [Use Edge Split Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges)
- [Add supporting geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23597/1853)
- [use Creases or bevel modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6426/1853)

Comment: If I had a dollar for every z-fighting question.

Comment: @iKlsR you would have about [10 dollars](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=z+fighting+is%3Aquestion) :)

Comment: Maybe if we start linking some of the best answers under the heading we can accomplish somethig together.

Comment: @David I was going to say that, I'd say it's probably close to 2 dozen tho. That's just a specific title.

Comment: Just added [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered/33790#33790) for objects not being visible in render, but are there in preview

Comment: Surprised no one has mentioned the many questions about [cycles render noise](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cycles+noise+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Just a tip for anyone editing this list you can use the share button below any post to get a shorter URL. Also you can simply past the link in here and SE will render the question title. (Which will make the links a lot cleaner and easier to change.)

Comment: Added "Differences between Renderers: Cycles, Blender Internal, and Game Engine" thanks to links provided by David and Gandalf3