# Is it ok to ask "cycles render versus blender render" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was thinking along the lines of bullet points comparing the two. (I'm asking for myself as I don't get the full implications).

Or would this just be too broad?

I found the answer to the 'proposed' FAQ quite useful: [Frequently Asked Questions on Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/frequenty-asked-questions-on-blender-stack-exchange)

Seems like it would be a good place for such.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5820/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you *can* ask that type of question, its not off topic, but I expect it will get closed as a duplicate of one of the following.

[Cycles vs Internal for a small animated outdoor scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7300/2217)
[How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5820/2217)
[Cycles vs internal vs game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/60486/2217)

Do note though, that this type of question if not worded very well, has a tendency to get closed as "*primarily opinion-based*."

If you already read through those, and still have a question about something specific (bullet points may get it closed as "*Too Broad*") then absolutely ask away.

Comment: @gandalf3 & David - wow, I did search for several variations and didn't find any of those. OK, good, don't want to dup.  Might add your lists of links to the 'FAQ' answer my OP mentions.  Hmmm... obviously, the key to triggering relevant 'related questions' while writing new question's subject line is nailing the right word or two for the search to get specific. Not always so obvious is Blender's jargon, requiring a certain amount of knowledge beforehand. I'd not have guessed "Internal" was the keyword ... I know *thanks* are frowned on, but, well, you know:_____! :))

Comment: Done: added "Differences between Renderers: Cycles, Blender Internal, and Game Engine" in http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1068/1332